# Move GTK window below all windows

Tags: python, gtk

I am writing a code that resembles a widget like Rainmeter. I want to move the widget down to just the desktop in the stacking order of the videos, but when I use `win.set_keep_below(True)`. It makes the buttons on my widget not clickable anymore. I am using python3 and gtk.

Here's the code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib
from datetime import datetime

import now_playing
import clock_date

if __name__ == '__main__':
    style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    style_provider.load_from_path('styles.css')

    win = Gtk.Window(name='toplevel')
    win.set_title('Desktop Clock')
    win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    win.set_default_size(600, 500)
    win.set_decorated(False)
    win.set_skip_taskbar_hint(True)
    win.set_skip_pager_hint(True)
  
    win.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.DESKTOP)  
    win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

    screen = win.get_screen()
    visual = screen.get_rgba_visual()
    if visual:
        win.set_visual(visual)
    else:
        print('Your screen may not support transparency')

    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    grid.set_name('grid')
    grid.set_column_homogeneous(True)

    clock_widget = clock_date.DesktopClockWidget()
    now_playing_widget = now_playing.NowPlayingWidget()

    grid.attach(clock_widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    grid.attach(now_playing_widget, 0, 1, 1, 1)

    win.add(grid)

    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
        Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
        style_provider,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
    )

    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```